# What are the induced functions $f_A(x, y)$ and $f_B(x, y, z)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, induction

$$\text{Let } A =\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\text{and } B =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**Then they ask me for the title:** What are the induced functions $f_A(x, y)$ and $f_B(x, y, z)$ ?

I'm having a very tough time finding out what ***'induced functions'*** actually means. It is not in my book for the course, and I can't find anything on the internet about it.

Comment: I think they're just the application of the matrices to the vectors

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do I need to find the vector products, is that the solution?

Comment: call $z$ the (vertical) vector $[x,y]$. Then $f_A(x,y) = Az$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure "induced function" just means the associated function given by usual matrix multiplication applied to column vectors on the right. I'll assume that your domains are supposed to be $\mathbf{R}^2$ and $\mathbf{R}^3$. Then, $A$ defines a map $f_A: \mathbf{R}^2\to \mathbf{R}^2$ by 
$$ f_A(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}
2&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
2x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}.$$
That is, $f_A(x,y)=(2x,y)$. A similar process will show what $f_B(x,y,z)$ is. Note that based on the dimensions of the matrix, $f_B: \mathbf{R}^3\to \mathbf{R}^2$.

As a remark, the upshot here is that matrices encode linear transformations when you fix bases for the domain and codomain. I implicitly assumed the standard bases for $\mathbf{R}^3, \mathbf{R}^2$ here.